# Change default shell command in the Robomon

Tags: robo3t

Is there any way to change the default shell command in Robomongo which is shown every time a new tab is open?

I want shell to show this:

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').find({})
```

to this:

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').find({}).sort({"date":-1})
```

every time I open a new tab.